# DB2 SQL Scubbing Data in a Select Statement with dynamic columns

Tags: sql, db2-400

We have an AS400 using DB2 of course, and I need to copy customer data to a new location for analysis, but it has to be scrubbed to protect sensitive information.  I’m doing this with about 30-40 tables.  The stored proc is getting big…

Anyway, for a brief example, say the data looks a little like this for columns, and in the 2nd row, the result of the copied data:

```
Col1 | Col2 | Name                  | Sex |  SS#      | Age | Col7 | Col8 |
______________________________________________________________________________________________
 *   |  *   | Case when Sex = F,    |  *  | 111111111 |  *  |  *   |  *   |
            | then Jane Doe else    |
            | John Smith end        |
```

My first attempt at this was to do a massive insert and then update, something like:

```
Insert into New_Table (Select * from Old_Table) ;
Update New_Table 
    set Name = ( Case when Sex = ‘F’ then ‘Jane Doe’ else ‘John Smith’  End),
        SS# = 111111111 ;
```

The problem  is that on a million rows, 200 columns, and triggers on the tables, the insert statement is fast, but the update is painfully slow – as in hours.  So with the help of Stack, I tried the following:

```
Insert into New_Table (Select Col1, Col2, 
    (Case when Sex = ‘F’ then ‘Jane Doe’ else ‘John Smith’ End), 
    Sex, 111111111, Age, Col7, Col8)
```

Worked like a champ - thanks team Stack!!

Now, I have another problem.  I have developers with a nasty habit of adding columns to these tables and I’m not on their team.  These tables have 200 columns and when I run into an error, the modifications can be interesting when I have to find the new columns

So I’m trying to come up with a way to BUILD a SQL statement on the fly and execute it, so the columns are flexible.  Granted, it’ll add another second to the statement to build it, but compared with the hours of labor when a mistake happens, it’ll be well worth it.

I was thinking about using something like a column lookup and then substitution into just the columns I want, building the SQL statement and then an Exec to call it.  I just can’t think of how to do it.  As for building the statement, it can take a bit of time when compared to the run time of the queries.  For instance, I can pull columns with:

```
Select COLUMN_NAME from Sysibm.columns where tbname = 'old_table' AND table_schema = ‘MySchema’.
```

Maybe I can put that into a variable, then search for the columns I know (name, ss#) and replace them, then build a SQL statement and EXEC it?  The result of the select statement for the columns (above) though doesn't lend itself well to a comma delimited list like I need.  As far as I can figure out.

Thoughts anyone?

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:
`Insert into New_Table (Select * from Old_Table)`

Is never a good idea in **production** code.  You should always explicitly list the columns you want.

```
Insert into 
New_Table (Col1, Col2, Name, Sex, SS#, Age, Col7, Col8)
(Select Col1, Col2, 
    (Case when Sex = ‘F’ then ‘Jane Doe’ else ‘John Smith’ End), 
    Sex, 111111111, Age, Col7, Col8)
```

Any new columns added to the table should have appropriate defaults.  Now your process won't break when a column is added.

Of course your scrubbed data will have defaults for new columns, this may or may not be an issue.  Thus, duplicating data is the one exception that proves the rule never to use  `SELECT *` in production.

Your idea of using syscolumns is a good one, also there's the [List Fields (QUSLFLD) API](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/apis/quslfld.htm).  You're going to have to build your comma delimited list one columns at a time in a loop.

If it were me, I'd build two lists.  One for any columns I don't have to scrub, and one for columns to scrub.  At the same time, you build the replacement 
select text.  That would allow your statement to be built like so:

```
wSQL = 'insert into new_table (' + wNonSrub + ',' + wSrub + ')'
        + ' (select ' + wNonScub + ',' + wReplacement 
        + ' from old_table' + ')';
```

One other possible idea...Put a before Insert/Update trigger on the table that's suppose to have the scrubbed data.  That trigger can scrub the data before it gets written to the table.  Honestly, I kind of like this idea the best.  It'd ensure the data is scrubbed even if somebody manually copies data instead of using the process you're building.

Comment: Two lists - interesting idea.  And loop through eh?  I'll try that.  Also, that's an interesting idea about actuallly LISTING the columns I'm updating and then allowing defaults.  Not bad.  Hadn't thought of that because of the 200 column thing, but it makes sense to use defaults.  I'll work on all of these and see if I can pull it off.  Thanks!!

Comment: Yep, it's a pain to list 200 columns.  But for production code, it's a best practice.  It's really not that hard to copy and paste a list of the columns currently in a table.  A decent text editor lets you add the needed comma.

Comment: Hey, do you know if there's a performance hit to an insert statement if the fields are not all in order?  At a million rows and 250 columns, this "could" matter, but maybe not?  Maybe SQL puts it all in order first?

Comment: Good question. After quick test on a 7.1 system with 6.5M rows and 14 columns, it would appear that the answer is no.

Comment: Not quite there, but this is going to work for me.  I appreciate the assistance.  It'll make the code easier to read as well.  I'll loose a few seconds, but on a 1 hr job, it's not bad.  :D  Thanks again!  PS>  I didn't use the trigger because I'm going to have several "versions" of this and it would require a chunk of modifications and my production team would have a heart attack.  I can do the rest without them noticing, mostly.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Speed up inserts on the AS400**.  You may have a lot of logical files built over the table you are inserting records into.  Change these logical files to REBLD(*DELAY)

```
CHGLF   mylib/mylogicalfile   rebld(*delay)
```

The only side effect is the first person and only the first person to open the file on any given day may have to wait a few seconds while the access path is being rebuilt.